# Jquery multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select one input box, But because i may have more than one inputs, i am trying to limit the one i am selecting. Here is my jquery code that select the the input but for some reason it doesn't work. Is theresomething i am doing wrong? This is be executed once the document is ready.

```
if ( $("input[name='RETURN.URL'][value='http://link.com?TYPE=P&amp;PID=ST-L09F166&amp;CONSTITUENCY=WBST']").length > 0 )
{
    alert("Transcript report");
}
else
{
    alert("Not Transcript Report");
}
```

Here the html

```
<input type="hidden" name="RETURN.URL" value="http://link.com?TYPE=P&amp;PID=ST-L09F166&amp;CONSTITUENCY=WBST">
<input type="hidden" name="SUBMIT_OPTIONS" value="">
```

Comment: drop the [value] qualifier... It's probably broken.  Also:  add a class and use that as the selector $('input.report');

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What is the purpose of your code? Can you have the same name several times? Error message?

Comment: @Richard: In that case an ID is more appropriate if he wants to target a specific input.

Comment: @glautrou Sure, ID would work too. Just anything except for "value".  Value shouldn't be used as a CSS Selector filter.

Comment: I would agree, that an id would be awsome, however i don't actually generate the html has the html page is generated dynamically, in which i have no control on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML entities are translated before they're shown in the browser, therefor `&amp;` becomes `&` and so forth. So when you're filtering the selector you're looking for something that's been translated into something else.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YBqQJ/).

Without getting into details of why you're selecting input elements this way, you just need to understand what I said and change the selector to:

```
$("input[name='RETURN.URL'][value='http://link.com?TYPE=P&PID=ST-L09F166&CONSTITUENCY=WBST']")
```

Comment: Wow thank you, this is what i was looking into, and it totally make sense, I agree filtering the input that i am looking might not be the best, but i don't really generate the html unless i use jquery.

Answer (score 5):

Your selector is using the HTML escaped attribute value:

```
[value='http://link.com?TYPE=P&amp;PID=ST-L09F166&amp;CONSTITUENCY=WBST']
```

The actual value of the selector should use `&` and not `&amp;`:

```
[value='http://link.com?TYPE=P&PID=ST-L09F166&CONSTITUENCY=WBST']
```

The value was HTML escaped so that the value would be correctly represented within the attribute, but the query selector needs to match by the actual value.

You'd probably be better off using a simple selector such as a class. This is particularly important, as the URL represented in the `[value]` attribute could have its query string parameters in any order and represent the same resource.

Comment: Dammit, you beat me by 1 minute. Feel free to use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjKFm/) if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery attr() method

```
if($("input[value='http://link.com?TYPE=P&PID=ST-L09F166&CONSTITUENCY=WBST']").attr('name') == 'RETURN.URL'){
 alert("Transcript report");
}
else
{
    alert("Not Transcript Report");
}
```

Unless otherwise, these contents are dynamically added, it is better to give this input an id, and access via it.

Comment: How would it set the value? cause i really don't want to set the anything

Comment: @Richard: I have actually edited with a modified use of attr() method. My initial answer would indeed set the value.

Comment: @Jseb: I have edited my answer with a modified use of attr() method. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value instead of using it as a selector.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRwpg/)</kbd>

```
if ( $("input[name='RETURN.URL']").val().length > 0 )
{
    alert("Transcript report");
}
else
{
    alert("Not Transcript Report");
}
```

Comment: Please don't abuse the `<kbd>` element, it's meant for marking up user input (such as keyboard buttons), not for making your link stand out.

Comment: Come on, folks. Let's not get into a fight over a simple formatting element. It doesn't really matter which way it's used here, so just let it go.

Answer (score 0):

lose the dot in `RETURN.URL` (its not a preferred way of adding names with dots to input elements)

& use `$('input[name=RETURNURL]').val().length`